# Plotting a line in ggplot with three different subsets with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to creat a plot with 3 colors on the same line based on the "Recorte column" which you can check on the sample bellow:

```
Legenda           `Hora da publicaçã~ Alcance `Curtidas e rea~ Comentários Compartilhament~ Resultados
  <chr>             <dttm>                <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl> <lgl>     
1 "Lucielle Lauren~ 2020-10-13 05:49:48      93                0           0                0 NA        
2 "Lucielle Lauren~ 2020-10-13 05:57:12    2827              164          10                0 NA        
3 "Assista agora a~ 2020-10-13 15:34:43    2641               68           1                0 NA        
4 "Acompanhe agora~ 2020-10-23 09:07:32    3063               65           1                0 NA        
5 "\U0001f535 Esta~ 2020-11-12 16:29:55    4578              105          17                0 NA        
6 "Em respeito ao ~ 2020-10-23 16:48:41    4891              227          17                6 NA
```

This is the column which i want to use to subset the line in 3 diferent labels, representing 3 stages in the timeline the graph is demonstrating.

```
> head(campanhalutudo$Recorte)
[1] "Periodo 1" "Periodo 1" "Periodo 1" "Periodo 2" "Periodo 3" "Periodo 2"
```

This line of code produces the base graph without any attempt to subset the line

```
`graflutudo <- ggplot(campanhalutudo, aes(x = `Hora da publicação`, y = Alcance), label = "periodo") + 
    geom_line(color = "Purple") +
    geom_line(aes(y = mean(Alcance)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 85000, by = 10000)) +
    scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%d"),
                     date_breaks = "4 days") +
    theme_light()`
```

[image]

I've tried using the following code to color the line:

```
    graflutudo<- ggplot(campanhalutudo, aes(x=`Hora da publicação`, y = Alcance, factor= (Recorte)), label = "periodo") + 
geom_line(color = "Purple") +
geom_line(aes(y = mean(Alcance)), color = "red", linetype = "dotted") +
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%m-%d"),
date_breaks = "4 days") + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 85000, by = 10000)) +
theme_light()
```

It returned the same graph without any coloring other than the already used purple.

I was also thinking that maybe this isn't even the best way to showcase the 3 different time periods in the timeline, something like bars that subest the line could also do the trick, any tips are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_line(aes(color = Recorte)) +`? Then you could use `scale_color_manual` for control over what colors are assigned based on Recorte value.

Comment: do i just add that below my current "ggplot(campanhalutudo, aes("  ? I'll try it out now!

Comment: I think so. Your current line `geom_line(color = "Purple") +` will combine show a single series, ignoring whatever is in `Recorte`. If you want three purple lines, add `geom_line(aes(group = Recorte), color = "purple")`. If you want three lines with different colors, use `geom_line(aes(color = Recorte))`.

Comment: It worked! It's looking pretty darn good now! If you put in answer format i'll mark it as the correct answer. Also, i'll edit the post to reference you for the help, pretty simple but save my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate purple lines for each series distinguished by the `Recorte` column, you can use `geom_line(aes(group = Recorte), color = "purple")`

If you want separate lines with different colors, you could use `geom_line(aes(color = Recorte))` and combine that with something like `scale_color_manual(values = c("Periodo 1" = "purple", "Periodo 2" = "darkorchid", "Periodo 3" = "darkmagenta"))` if you want to specify different purple colors for the various series.